# How many possible ways can a rectangular space be filled with squares of 2 colors, so that the contiguous edges never have the same color?

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible ways can a rectangular space be filled with squares of 2 colors, so that the contiguous edges never have the same color?

[image: Example of square]

[image: Example of correctly filled rectangular space]

[image: Example of incorrectly filled rectangular space]

Comment: Is the side length of the squares on the inside of each rectangle fixed?

Comment: yes, they are of fixed length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have rectangles of horizontal width $n$ and height $m$ that are tiled by quadratic tiles split diagonally, as in the figures of the OP.

We can place the top left tile in $4$ ways. Then we can add $n-1$ tiles in the first row with $2$ choices for each next tile, and we can add $m-1$ tiles in the first column with $2$ choices for each next tile. From then on everything is determined, because the fourth tile in an L-shape can be placed in exactly $1$ way, whatever the situation.

The total number $N$ of tilings therefore is given by
$$N=4\cdot 2^{n-1}\cdot 2^{m-1}=2^{m+n}\ .$$